# Get JSON object based on another JSON value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have an array for id's and contents for that id in JSON response. how can I get the contents based on the id I have received?

For example, if ID is 1 ( returns from json ) I want to get json data by "data.id" ( ID is 1 ), because I put contents in array named ID itself. I can't substitute the ID there, it looks for json object itself.

```
user_data = JSON.parse(data);
jQuery.each(user_data.id, function( key, value )
{
    var ref_id = value;
    jQuery.each(user_data."{REF_ID HERE}",function(key1,value1){
        console.log("Works");
    });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

This is the JSON response i am receiving. There is an array of id's,i want to get contents for each id

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for brackets.

```
user_data[ref_id]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please see edited question and give me your suggestion?